# How to use a "non-windows store" app in assigned access on windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, kiosk

I have a software program for my business that I need to run in kiosk mode or "Assigned access". The program I want to use does not come up as an option when I select the program I want to use in assigned access mode. Is there a setting or code I can change to make the program eligible for assigned access?

Comment: Is the software in question a Modern UI app, or a regular Windows Desktop app?

Comment: "The only requirement is that the selected application **needs to be a modern application** not a desktop application." - http://blogs.technet.com/b/canitpro/archive/2013/12/17/step-by-step-enabling-kiosk-mode-in-windows-8-1-via-assigned-access.aspx  Note, it needs to be a Modern App, but doesn't necessarily have to come from the store.

Comment: There isn't a work around for the default kiosk mode.  There is third-party software that would replace it is you want a win32 traditional desktop application to be locked

Comment: Not happening. Only works on Windows Store apps. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I have found to make Windows 8 .exe "non-modern" app into a kiosk is to replace the Explorer shell under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\WinLogon\Shell` and put in the path to your .exe. Beware this will limit some functionality, so you could lose some functions you would want in the process.